# GNU Screen - terminal size - scroll left-right (wrapping disabled)

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I use GNU Screen on Suckless st or xterm. One of the reasons is for scrollback, using copy mode, c-a esc.

I need to examine some very long and **wide** logs and also some interactive Oracle SQL*Plus wide output. Wrapping doesn't help me, I need the wide lines to **not** wrap. I've set `:wrap off` to Screen, but I cannot scroll left-right in copy mode, only up-down.

So, if my terminal size is 80x25 for example, line wrapping is off, is there any way to scroll and view the rest characters after the 80th column?

I can also use rxvt without or with screen if there is a way to achieve my two goals there (no wrapping, scrolling left-right and up-down). Don't want to start using tmux, no time to get into it, but if it's possible there notify - for future reference.

Comment: Why not just use `less -S`?

Comment: `less -S` is fine for logs but not for interactive apps like SQL*Plus.